# Can I throw a custom exception within except clause without causing: "During handling of..."

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, try-except

So first of all, if this isn't best practice in your opinion I'd love to discuss that in the comments.

My problem is as follows, I try to find a file based on user input. If the file cannot be found I get a `FileNotFoundError`. Which is great, but I want to give a proper exception that'd describe the problem better. The users don't really know that a file being present decides if something is possible. So a `FileNotFoundError` might look out of place. So what I currently have is:

```py
try:
    x = get_file(...)
except FileNotFoundError as e:  # Unsupported version
    raise MyOwnException(f"Explaining the problem")
```

The above works but the exception looks like so:

- `FileNotFoundError` & stack trace
- "During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:"
- `MyOwnException` & stack trace

I'd love to only have `MyOwnException`. To achieve this, I understand you can do:

```py
try:
    x = get_file(...)
except FileNotFoundError as e:  # Unsupported version
    file_not_found = True
if file_not_found:
    raise MyOwnException(f"Explaining the problem")
```

And also I can check if the file exists using `os.path.isfile(file_path)`. But I'm hoping for a more elegant solution since checking if a file exist before opening is generally discouraged.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can raise an exception without the context of the previous exception using:

```
raise MyOwnException("Explaining the problem") from None
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#exception-chaining

Comment: Ah, `exception-chaining`, that's the term I didn't know. Thanks! This is perfect!